# Downloaded Facebook archive consists of two files. How to join them?

Tags: facebook, download, facebook-archive

When I used the "Download Your Information" feature of Facebook, it produced two zip files. Both files have a **messages** folder and a large file named **facebook_1479114225.zip.enc**. There are no instructions as to how to join these two zip files. I cannot just extract the contents of both files into the same directory as the second extraction would overwrite the first large **.enc** file.

Only one of the files contains an index.html file and I am able to access that page to read contents going back several years, but I have no idea how to merge these two files.

Comment: Since Facebook moved its "Download your information" functionality to Meta Accounts Center, I haven't got an .enc file ever since.

Answer (score 3):

This is as far as I think I've figured it out:

The .enc extension indicates that the file is encrypted. Checking the syntax for OpenSSL on https://www.techquintal.com/openssl-commands-examples/
and we find out how to decrypt an encrypted file! We're halfway there!

However, what password was used for the encryption is beyond me! I tried using my Facebook password to no avail.

This is the time when we all scream in unison, "Some assistance, please!"